# Will my SSD need to be formatted at any point?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, pci-express, enclosures

I'm going to buy a laptop soon and it comes with a 512 GB SSD PCIe in it's main slot and an empty secondary PCIe slot that can go upto 1 TB. Hence, I will also be purchasing a 1 TB SSD PCIe. I wish to move the files from my previous laptop to this new SSD using an enclosure and then place the SSD into the new laptop's secondary slot. I'm worried if the drive will need to be formatted at any point (maybe when placing it into the new laptop).

PS: I'm very new at this kind of stuff, so sorry if the question sounds silly.

Comment: If you format after copying files, it will destroy the new files. So NO you should not need to format it after copying files, unles you want to lose the files.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to format ssd to place it in the laptop after copying the files.

A hard drive can be used in any computer. A **new** hard drive typically needs to be formatted before it can be used for the first time, but it has nothing to do with the computer or moving the hard drive to a new computer. After formatted the harddrive for the first time there is no need to reformat the hard drive.
However, you should be aware that different operating systems (Windows, Linux etc) use different file system formats, this is one of the reasons why you are reformatting a hard drive. The file system format is the format you choose when formatting the hard drive and it is the main reasons why a hard drive needs to be formatted.

[How to format a new hard drive on Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-format-new-hard-drive-windows-10)

Comment: Format is a very sloppy word in English and has many meanings (even in this context).  Here, the term "format" is being used interchangeably with "partitioning".. and yet, there is no description of what that is.  Traditionally, "format" means wipe all of the blocks of a disk.. now, it can mean [any number of things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_formatting)

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I chose to answer a simple question. Can I copy my files to a hard drive and move it to a new computer without having to delete my data at any point. The answer is yes, but I warn him that he may have to reformat if he do it wrong. There is no need to elaborate on that explanation as it will be an answer to a completely different question. I'm also trying not to get too technical as he's very new at this kind of stuff.

Comment: Fair enough.. :)  I am not trying to rock the boat and I didn't deduct points.. just pointing out the ambiguity of the word.